# how can i fix Unable to generate valid Navmesh error

Tags: game-engine

i have two files and when i am running the file in which i created navmesh that time it is running fine without any error but when same file is running from another file it shows error as 
unable to initialize image(0) in MAMaterial, image will not be available
Converting navmesh: Error! There are no vertices!
Converting navmesh: Error! Can't get raw vertices and indices from mesh
Navmesh: Unable to generate valid Navmesh
please help me

## #

file in which i created navmesh
[image]

## #

file from which i am opening file of navmesh
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information like the navmesh related configurations, how you made the navmesh?, where and how you set up the object which use the navmesh?. I dont understand why you are getting and image error, I just made a simple test with 2 blends, 1st) Cube click and load 2nd) one navmesh and a objects seeking other objects, Everything worked no errors.

Comment: can i send files to you

Comment: Yes please use [https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), to upload put the url of this question then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/95197/edit) and post the link.

Comment: i don't know what was the  error but i did some changes and know it is working.thanks for support